# Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided enctype='multipart/form-data' usage issue

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, web-deployment

im working on file upload for a profile so i need to upload data as well as profile picture so to upload files in form we need use this right? enctype='multipart/form-data'  when I'm using this all my rest data is converting into null and when i remove this from my form I'm getting an error "Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided"
So I'm unable to resolve this issue from past few hours hope some can help me
here is the whole code
JSP

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*,java.text.*,javax.servlet.*,
 java.security.MessageDigest,java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException 
   ,java.io.File,java.io.PrintWriter,java.awt.List,java.nio.file.Path,
   java.nio.file.Paths,javax.servlet.http.Part,
     javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig,java.io.IOException"%> 

  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");%>
    <%!
    static javax.servlet.http.Part part;
    %>
    <%!
    private String extractFileName(Part part) 
    {
        String contetntDisp=part.getHeader("content-disposition");
        String[] items=contetntDisp.split(";");
        for(String s: items)
        {
            if(s.trim().startsWith("filename"))
            {
                return s.substring(s.indexOf("=")+2,s.length()-1);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }  
    %>
    <%
    
    String username=(String) session.getAttribute("nkey");
    String f_name =request.getParameter("f_name");
    String l_name =request.getParameter("l_name");

    part =request.getPart("profile_link");
    //String p_l=request.getParameter("profile_link");
    String id_link =request.getParameter("id_link");
    //int age =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
    String age =request.getParameter("age");
    String gender =request.getParameter("gender");
    String address =request.getParameter("address");
    //int pincode =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pincode"));       
    String pincode =request.getParameter("pincode");
    String qualification =request.getParameter("qualification");
    String year =request.getParameter("year");
    String college_name =request.getParameter("college_name");
    String state =request.getParameter("state");
    String country =request.getParameter("country");
    %>
    <%!
    private static final String SAVE_DIR="Pictures";
    %>
    <% 
    PrintWriter outt=response.getWriter();
    String savePath="C:/Users/thots/Desktop/My World/internsip/Student_Portal 2.0/WebContent"+File.separator+SAVE_DIR;
    File fileSaveDir=new File(savePath);

    String fileName=extractFileName(part);
    
    part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
    
    String filePath=savePath+File.separator + fileName;     

    try 
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Student_Portal 2.0","root","");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into student_details values('"+username+"','"+f_name+"','"+l_name+"','"+filePath+"','"+id_link+"','"+age+"','"+gender+"','"+address+"','"+pincode+"','"+qualification+"','"+year+"','"+college_name+"','"+state+"','"+country+"')");
        if(i>0)
        {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            Statement stt=con.createStatement();
            String sql="update user_login set P_Status='1' where username='"+username+"'";
            stt.executeUpdate(sql);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    %>
```

HTML code

```
<form action="add_student_details.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div>
                                    <label for="img">Upload Profile Picture</label>
                                     <input name="profile_link" type="file" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                    <label for="img">Upload Your ID card</label>
                                    <input name="id_link" type="file" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                     <input name="f_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <input name="l_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                     <input name="age" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                      <select name="gender" class="form-control" required>
                                        <option>Male</option>
                                        <option >Female</option>
                                      </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                <textarea name="address" rows="4" cols="55" placeholder="Your Address" id="w3review" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div>
                                <input name="pincode" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Pincode" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <br>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                         <h4>Educational Info</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                          <select name="qualification" class="form-control" required>
                                          <option selected disabled>Select Your Qualification</option>
                                            <option>B.Tech</option>
                                            <option >B.E</option>
                                          </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                          <select name="year" class="form-control" required>
                                          <option selected disabled>Select Your Year</option>
                                            <option>I</option>
                                            <option >II</option>
                                            <option>III</option>
                                            <option >IV</option>
                                          </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div >
                                          <select name="college_name" class="form-control" required>
                                          <option selected disabled>Select Your College</option>
                                            <option>ABCD College Of Engineering And Technology</option>
                                            <option >XYZ College Of Engineering And Technology</option>
                                          </select>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                          <select name="state" class="form-control" required>
                                          <option selected disabled>Select Your State</option>
                                            <option>Telangana</option>
                                            <option >Kerala</option>
                                          </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                          <select name="country" class="form-control" required>
                                          <option selected disabled>Select Your Country</option>
                                            <option>India</option>
                                            <option>United States</option>
                                          </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <hr>
                                <center>
                                <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
                                </center>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                       </form>
```

added this too but still the error did not resolve
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024,
maxFileSize=1024*1024*5, maxRequestSize=1024*1024*5*5)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding maxSwallowSize = "-1" into tomcat's server.xml file. example below.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
maxSwallowSize = "-1"/>
```